# PowerApp Gallery with sort() and distinct()

Tags: gallery, powerapps

I created a Gallery with a Title == Name and a subtitle == First Name by item.

I want this gallery to be sorted and remove duplicates.

I tried this:

```
Sort(Distinct(Data_source, Name), Result)
```

The problem is that I get Title == Name and subtitle == Name instead of Fisrt Name.

How can I keep different fields ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noticed, the [`Distinct` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-distinct) will only return the distinct values from the selected column, and discard the other ones. If you want to preserve the other values, you can use the [`GroupBy` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-groupby), and take one of the elements of the group. Something along the lines of the expression below:

```
ForAll(
    GroupBy(
        Data_source,
        "Name",
        "ByName"),
    Patch(
        { Name: ThisRecord.Name },
        First(ThisRecord.ByName)
    )
)
```